# replace substring in R

Tags: r, string

I have a list of strings, for which I must change a certain substring from caps to lowcaps. How can I implement this efficiently in R?

Here's a sublist:

```
>head(ID)

"1007_PM_S_AT"
"1053_PM_AT"  
"117_PM_AT"   
"121_PM_AT"    
"1255_PM_G_AT" 
"1294_PM_AT"
```

I need to change everything after PM to lowercase.

Comment: have a look at the `stringr` package. `str_locate` may help.

Comment: I am, but are you aware a one line solution for this?

Comment: I sure am. But I need to know what have you tried?

Comment: Not much, I am new to R. I am messing around with the Map function

Comment: `gsub('(?<=PM)(.*)', '\\L\\1', test, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option, would be to wrap `tolower()` in a `sub()` call

```
R> test <- c("1007_PM_S_AT", "1053_PM_AT", "117_PM_AT", "121_PM_AT", "1255_PM_G_AT", "1294_PM_AT")
R> sub("pm", "PM", tolower(test))
[1] "1007_PM_s_at" "1053_PM_at"   "117_PM_at"    "121_PM_at"    "1255_PM_g_at" "1294_PM_at"
```

Another alternative (probably not as good here) that can be useful is to use the replacement function `regmatches<-`.

```
matches <- gregexpr('(?<=PM)(.+)', test, perl=TRUE)              # match the string after PM
regmatches(test, matches) <- tolower(regmatches(test, matches))  # replace with lower case
```

Comment: Cheers! Thanks for thinking from the other direction. I was so upset about that stupid problem that I discarded logic.

Comment: Considering I do the same thing multiple times per day, I completely understand